# MariaDB: Select a row an amount of times defined in that row's column

Tags: mysql, select, mariadb

So I have a table like so:

```
| id   |   entries   | userId  |
--------------------------------
| 1    |       2     |   5     |
--------------------------------
| 2    |       5     |   3     |
--------------------------------
| 3    |       7     |   5     |
```

I need a query to select the same row "x" number of times where "x" is the value of the `entries` column.

So the above table would be output as such:

```
| id   |   entries   | userId  |
--------------------------------
| 1    |       2     |   5     |
--------------------------------
| 1    |       2     |   5     |
--------------------------------
| 3    |       2     |   5     |
--------------------------------
| 3    |       2     |   5     |
--------------------------------
| 3    |       2     |   5     |
--------------------------------
| 3    |       2     |   5     |
--------------------------------
| 3    |       2     |   5     |
--------------------------------
| 3    |       2     |   5     |
--------------------------------
| 3    |       2     |   5     |
--------------------------------
| 2    |       5     |   3     |
--------------------------------
| 2    |       5     |   3     |
--------------------------------
| 2    |       5     |   3     |
--------------------------------
| 2    |       5     |   3     |
--------------------------------
| 2    |       5     |   3     |
```

(A total of 9 rows for `userId` = 5 and a total of 5 rows for `userId` = 3)

Is there any way to do this with MariaDB?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes there is: Write a stored procedure which just repeats your output.

Comment: No. Handle issues of data display in application code